# Hyperdrive Thunderbolt 4 PowerHub no longer recognized

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, apple-silicon

My Hyperdrive Thunderbolt 4 PowerHub is no longer recognized by my M1 Max MacBook. It happened suddenly, perhaps after an OS update.

As I am using Apple Silicon I can't do any of the advised resetting of NVRAM or PRAM.

Frustratingly, Hyper doesn't answer my support tickets and have nothing I can see related to this issue.

When connected the LED simply flashes on and off.

It's a $300 hub. I can't afford to just throw it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, did you do an update?

Comment: Update what? I have updated the Mac but there's no way I know of to update the hub. The instructions provide no information on that. If I'm being spectacularly dumb please let me know.

Comment: "*perhaps after an OS update*" this one...

Comment: Everything is fully up-to-date.

Comment: It’s moot to reset SMC or NVRAM  because nothing in there deals with Thunderbolt.  I would start by moving the Hub to a different port. If you have any TB accessories (like a TB to Ethernet adapter) plug in directly to the Mac to bypass the Hub to ensure  your port is working.  If possible try plugging the Hub into a different Mac. If it fails there, the Hub is at fault and you can focus your attention there

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely the hub. I tried what you suggested before posting. I've also restarted the Mac every way I can think of. It's frustrating because the failure appears to be spontaneous and the thing is so damn expensive. Unfortunately their support page is filled with people decrying the lack of a response. It's pretty ominous.

Comment: I was just on their website and there’s no support documentation for that model. However, I did find an FAQ about Ventura updates; unfortunately it’s not applicable. When there’s an issue, you get an error on screen, not the whole hub dying.  You still may want to contact their support department

Comment: Their support department doesn't work sadly. I've sent tickets and they were merged last week but no detail was added at all. Very frustrating.

Comment: Ask for a refund from wherever you bought it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Hyperdrive Thunderbolt 4 PowerHub is no longer recognized… When connected the LED simply flashes on and off.

#### Your Hub has failed.

I know it’s not the words you wanted to hear, but the reality is the device is no longer responding.  There’s no manual on the [HyperDrive Support site](https://hypershop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)  to assist with diagnosis (as of this posting) but a flashing LED is usually indicative of a failure; especially when it starts the same time the device stopped working.

You can confirm this by some basic troubleshooting:

- Plug a different Thunderbolt device like a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter or a Thunderbolt drive directly into the Mac.  If it works there, the Mac and Thunderbolt port are verified to be good.
- Connect the Thunderbolt 4 Hub into a different computer (PC included).  If it cannot be detected there, then the issue is with the Hub itself and needs to be serviced.

#### Recommendation…

> It's a $300 hub. I can't afford to just throw it out. Any suggestions?

I know this stings.  Spending good money to buy something only to have it fail prematurely and receive no help seems like a brisk slap in the face.  If you must get a new dock, I highly recommend getting one from an established vendor; stay away from the “new players” no matter how flashy their wares are. Personally, I like the following manufacturers:

- Dell
- Caldigit
- Sonnet
- Kensignton

HP and Lenovo make docks as well, but I’m not a fan of those brands; YMMV.  The ones listed (especially Sonnet and Caldigit) above have been making docks and drive systems for a long, long time and have the experience to back it up.  Their prices may be higher than these new players, but when it comes to ensuring your data is available, they suddenly become a more cost effective purchase.

Comment: One name there has been doing (good) Mac stuff for more years than I care to remember…

Comment: Kramer and OWC are other manufacturers I trust for high quality products.

Comment: After all this the company has now responded and offered to take it back. I will be returning it shortly.

Comment: That’s good news.  At least you’re not out the $300